# Issues on custom login system for students in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I make a middleware RedirectIfNotStudent

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'student')
    {
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/student/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I create a new directory As StudentAuth for Authentication and these methods are there

```
public function showLoginForm()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('student')->check())
        {
            return redirect('/student');
        }

        return view('student.login');
    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::guard('student')->logout();
        return redirect('/student/login');
    }
```

I add a new row in Kernel File

```
'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotUser::class,
```

My Route for this is here

```
Route::get('student','StudentAuth\StudentAuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('student','StudentAuth\StudentAuthController@login');
```

Comment: this error is occure                                                                                Class App\Http\Controllers\StudentAuth\StudentAuthController does not exist

Comment: Is the namespace correct?

Comment: Can we see the namespace ?

Comment: i think so... but what it should be?

Comment: -->StudentAuthController                                                                                         <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

Answer (score 0):

StudentAuthController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
```

RedirectIfNotUser

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your namespace :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

With

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\StudentAuth;
```

Comment: Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\finalProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php on line 87 and defined

Answer (score 0):

StudentController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```